# Search for multiple strings across multiple workbooks and copy data

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I have borrowed some code that searches multiple excel workbooks for a string and tried to modify it to search for multiple strings instead. Unfortunately it seems to stop after searching for the first item in the array.

```vb
Sub SearchFolders()
   'Dim myArray As Variant
   'Dim myCounter As Long
    Dim xFso As Object
    Dim xFld As Object
    Dim xStrSearch As Variant
    Dim xStrPath As String
    Dim xStrFile As String
    Dim xOut As Worksheet
    Dim xWb As Workbook
    Dim xWk As Worksheet
    Dim xRow As Long
    Dim xFound As Range
    Dim xStrAddress As Variant
    Dim xFileDialog As FileDialog
    Dim xUpdate As Boolean
    Dim xCount As Long

    myArray = Array("item a", "item b", "item c", "item d")
    On Error GoTo ErrHandler
    Set xFileDialog = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
    xFileDialog.AllowMultiSelect = False
    xFileDialog.Title = "Select a Folder"
    
    If xFileDialog.Show = -1 Then
        xStrPath = xFileDialog.SelectedItems(1)
    End If
    If xStrPath = "" Then Exit Sub
    xUpdate = Application.ScreenUpdating
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Set xOut = Worksheets.Add
    For myCounter = 0 To UBound(myArray)
        MsgBox myCounter & "is the count no."
        xStrSearch = myArray(myCounter)
        MsgBox xStrSearch & "is the string"
        xRow = 1
    With xOut
        .Cells(xRow, 1) = "Workbook"
        .Cells(xRow, 2) = "Worksheet"
        .Cells(xRow, 3) = "Cell"
        .Cells(xRow, 4) = "Filler"
        .Cells(xRow, 5) = "Text in Cell"
        Set xFso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
        Set xFld = xFso.GetFolder(xStrPath)
        xStrFile = Dir(xStrPath & "\*.xls*")
        Do While xStrFile <> ""
            Set xWb = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=xStrPath & "\" & xStrFile, _
                UpdateLinks:=0, ReadOnly:=True, AddToMRU:=False)
            For Each xWk In xWb.Worksheets
                Set xFound = xWk.UsedRange.Find(xStrSearch)
                If Not xFound Is Nothing Then
                    xStrAddress = xFound.Address
                End If
                Do
                If xFound Is Nothing Then
                    Exit Do
                Else
                    xCount = xCount + 1
                    xRow = xRow + 1
                        .Cells(xRow, 1) = xWb.Name
                        .Cells(xRow, 2) = xWk.Name
                        .Cells(xRow, 3) = xFound.Address
                        .Cells(xRow, 5) = xFound.Value
                    End If
                    Set xFound = xWk.Cells.FindNext(After:=xFound)
                      
                Loop While xStrAddress <> xFound.Address
                myCounter = myCounter + 1
            Next
            xWb.Close (False)
            xStrFile = Dir
        Loop
        .Columns("A:D").EntireColum.AutoFit
    
    End With
    Next myCounter
    MsgBox xCount & "Cells have been found", , "filler"
    
ExitHandler:
        Set xOut = Nothing
        Set xWk = Nothing
        Set xWb = Nothing
        Set xFld = Nothing
        Set xFso = Nothing
        Application.ScreenUpdating = xUpdate
        Exit Sub
ErrHandler:
    MsgBox Err.Description, vbExclamation
    Resume ExitHandler
        
End Sub
```

Not sure what I've done wrong.
If possible, it would be great to also be able to return the value of `Column A` or copy `Columns A - H` into the sheet.

I.e. If `found.address` is `(C,4)` then also return `(A,4)`.

Many thanks!

Comment: Cannot follow the complete logic of your code (you have 4! nested loops), but for sure you shouldn't modify the running variable of a for-loop as you do with `myCounter`.

Comment: I tested your code with variable results. Some file paths worked OK and some only worked for the first file. I'm gonna see if I can figure it out. Do you run this in folders containing other macro enabled workbooks? It seems to throw an error on the next file after it checks a macro enabled workbook.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Very new to all this. Trying to clean things up at the moment. I am using it to filter through around 360+ macro enabled workbooks (in batches of around 30) but I'm not sure at which point the error gets triggered and if it is this code or that of the workbook being searched.

Comment: The first thing I would do is comment out or delete _On Error Goto Error_Handler_. You want to see where the error occurs, not just pop up message box and exit. You might also want to scatter some Debug.Assert and Debug.Print statements to help you find the cause of the problem. You should also think about whether this function could be broken up into several smaller functions which would help clarify the logic.

Comment: @YangGao if you are still stuck in about 18 hrs, @ me and I'll have another look Tomorrow evening.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you have a situation where your code does multiple things like:

- ask for a folder
- find all files in that folder
- find all cell matches in each sheet in each file

you're better off pushing any functionality which can be wrapped in its own sub/function into a stand-alone method, so you can focus on your actual task and its logic, instead of having it overwhelmed by all of the sub-tasks and their logic/rules.

Plus, once you've created your focused sub-methods, you can re-use them later.

Applying that approach to your task:

```vb
Sub SearchFolders()
    
    Dim arrSearch As Variant
    Dim rw As Long, s
    Dim folderPath As String, f, allFiles As Collection, allCells As Collection
    Dim wb As Workbook, ws As Worksheet, wsOut As Worksheet, c
    
    arrSearch = Array("item a", "item b", "item c", "item d")
    
    folderPath = SelectFolder()          'get a folder from the user
    If Len(folderPath) = 0 Then Exit Sub 'no selected folder
    
    Set allFiles = MatchingFiles(folderPath, "*.xls*") 'find all matching files
    If allFiles.Count = 0 Then
        MsgBox "No matching files found!"
        Exit Sub
    End If
   
    Set wsOut = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets.Add()
    wsOut.Range("A1:E1").Value = Array("Workbook", "Worksheet", _
                                       "Cell", "Filler", "Cell Text")
    rw = 2
    
    For Each f In allFiles                                  'loop files
        With Workbooks.Open(f, ReadOnly:=True)
            For Each ws In .Worksheets                      'loop workbooks
                For Each s In arrSearch                     'loop search terms
                    Set allCells = FindAll(ws.UsedRange, s)
                    For Each c In allCells                  'loop matches

                        wsOut.Cells(rw, 1).Resize(1, 5).Value = _
                            Array(.Name, ws.Name, c.Address, "", c.Value)

                        wsOut.Cells(rw, 6).Resize(1, 8).Value = _
                            c.entirerow.cells(1).resize(1, 8) 'copy A-H from row with c

                        rw = rw + 1
                    Next c
                Next s 'next search string
            Next ws    'next worksheet
            .Close False
        End With
    Next f             'next workbook
   
    wsOut.Range("A:D").EntireColumn.AutoFit
   
End Sub

'ask the user for a folder
Function SelectFolder() As String
    Dim rv As String
    With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
        .AllowMultiSelect = False
        .Title = "Select a Folder"
        If .Show = -1 Then rv = .SelectedItems(1)
    End With
    If Right(rv, 1) <> "\" Then rv = rv & "\" 'ensure trailing "\"
    SelectFolder = rv
End Function

'Return a collection of all files in folder `fPath` matching `pattern`
Function MatchingFiles(fPath As String, pattern As String)
    Dim f As Object, col As New Collection
    With CreateObject("scripting.filesystemobject").getfolder(fPath)
        For Each f In .Files
            If f.Name Like pattern Then col.Add f.Path
        Next f
    End With
    Set MatchingFiles = col
End Function

'Find all matches in a range and return as a collection of cells
'Note: adjust the Find() parameters to function as you need
'  (eg. exact vs partial match)
Public Function FindAll(rng As Range, val) As Collection
    Dim rv As New Collection, f As Range
    Dim addr As String

    Set f = rng.Find(what:=val, after:=rng.Cells(rng.Cells.Count), _
        LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
        SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False)
    If Not f Is Nothing Then addr = f.Address()

    Do Until f Is Nothing
        rv.Add f
        Set f = rng.FindNext(after:=f)
        If f.Address() = addr Then Exit Do
    Loop
    Set FindAll = rv
End Function
```